# Reference books on Number Theory.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I am preparing for my PhD viva on number theory. Currently I am reading "Elementary Number Theory" by Burton and "Introduction to the theory of numbers" by Niven and Zuckerman. Besides these, which book I should read in order to concrete my knowledge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ireland and Rosen: A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory is a must read.